# Contact 7 form styling issue

Tags: css

I'm attempting to create a form using contact 7 to save time with the validation and sanitization. However I seem to be having a problem with how its laid out - I've tried various things setting the width and floating each div but the fields don't want to seem to go on the same line.

Currently its at the bottom of this in the footer

I am trying to get it to look like the below image.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.first-row > p {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.first-row .wpcf7-text {
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
}
```